# My not very bad one

Tags: riddle, word

What word am I?

> First composed of "Badap ba daa ba da daa ba daa da deda daa Badap ba daa ba da daa ba daa da deda daa".
>   A benevolent dictator for life implicitly writes.
>   The beginning of people saying, "There's people waiting to be crucified out here."
>   And the back end of completely naked men!

Hint:

> There's a clue in the title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> Monty

First composed of "Badap ba daa ba da daa ba daa da deda daa Badap ba daa ba da daa ba daa da deda daa".

> The composer of the James Bond theme tune is **Monty** Norman

A benevolent dictator for life implicitly writes.

> Refers to BDFL Guido van Rossum who wrote most of the Python examples using phrases from **Monty** Python.

The beginning of people saying, "There's people waiting to be crucified out here."

> **Monty** Python's Life of Brian

And the back end of completely naked men!

> The Full **Monty**

Title

> Monty is an anagram of 'My not'

Comment: 100% correct :) )

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once for deciphering that rendering of an instrumental melody.

Comment: @question_asker Silver Shadow cracked it first. And I got it from a google search to make it more possible then inventing something completely indecipherable myself.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like every clue points to

> Monty Python's Life of Brian

First composed of "Badap ba daa ba da daa ba daa da deda daa Badap ba daa ba da daa ba daa da deda daa".

> "Always look on the bright side of life" is sung by the crucified people

A benevolent dictator for life implicitly writes.

> no clue yet, the emperor in the movie is Pontius Pilatus

The beginning of people saying, "There's people waiting to be crucified out here."

> Quote from the crucification scene

And the back end of completely naked men!

> also no clue

Comment: So close!  You found the qutoe correctly.But Silver Shadow got the song right. And nothing to do with Pontius Pilatus.

Answer (score 2):

The Word is

> Doctor

First composed of "Badap ba daa ba da daa ba daa da deda daa Badap ba daa ba da daa ba daa da deda daa".

> Possibly the song Seems James Bond Announcement. The First Composed of James Bond Series is Dr.No

A benevolent dictator for life implicitly writes.The beginning of people saying, "There's people waiting to be crucified out here."

> Crucified sort of like in the Operation theater?

And the back end of completely naked men!

> Everybody goes Naked in front of Doctor.

Comment: Clever but wrong. Warm with first bit.

Comment: Schorsch has found the quote.

Comment: nice Question @PaulEvans ... it was very interesting though

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Judgement?

First composed of "Badap ba daa ba da daa ba daa da deda daa Badap ba daa ba da daa ba daa da deda daa".

> No clue. Maybe a song

A benevolent dictator for life implicitly writes.

> A benevolent dictator must be a fair judge and therefore casts fair judgement in their writings.

The beginning of people saying, "There's people waiting to be crucified out here."

> They must be judged before being executed

And the back end of completely naked men!

> men! looks like the last 4 letters of judgement

Comment: Quite good but wrong. Much more obvious once you get it.